# match space or newline in sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have read and search, but I don't understand what's wrong with it, I want to match: a space, the string 00011, and either a space or a new line.

```
sed 's:\(\s\)\(00011\)\([\s\n]\):\1$03\3:g'
```

EDIT: the data looks like this:

```
ADD    00000 00001 00011
LSH    00011 00100 01111
ADD    00011 10100 00010
JSR    00011101000111010101100010
```

and `$03` is just a string to replace the `00011`

I want to end up with something like this:

```
ADD    00000 00001 $03
LSH    $03 00100 01111
ADD    $03 10100 00010
JSR    00011101000111010101100010
```

Thanks

Comment: What does your input data look like? Note that since `sed` reads newline-delimited data, it will never see the newlines themselves.

Comment: What does that `$03` stand for? It won't be expanded due to the single quotes, and if it were, it would expand to e.g. `bash3` (given your shell is `bash`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sed works on a line at a time and it will strip the newlines when processing each line.

So, in order to do what you want, you should match the end of line anchor (`$`) rather than a literal newline character.

This should work:

```
sed 's:\(\s\)\(00011\)\(\s\|$\):\1$03\3:g'
```

Comment: I already tried that, but I missed the backslash before the pipe, thanks, it works perfectly.

Comment: This would fail for data such as `00011 00011`.

Comment: even with the `g`?

Comment: @onlycparra That's correct, the `/g` doesn't help here, since the space between matches will be matched at the end of the first regex, so it will not be considered at the start of the second regex match. You can test that yourself. Matching word boundaries is definitely better here!

Comment: It took me quite a while to discover that this didn't work for me, because I was using the pipe (`|`) as a separator in sed, which doesn't seem to mix well with the logical OR (`\|`).  Using `/` (or `:`) as a separator fixes that.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ sed 's/\<00011\>/$03/g' file
ADD    00000 00001 $03
LSH    $03 00100 01111
ADD    $03 10100 00010
JSR    00011101000111010101100010
```

The `\<` and `\>` matches the zero-width word boundaries at the start and end of a word, respectively.  BSD `sed` would also recognise `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`, and GNU `sed` also understands `\b` as a word boundary.

`sed` will never see the newlines in the input data.  Also, `\s` is specific to GNU `sed`.  To match a space character in standard `sed` just use a literal space (to match a space-or-tab, use `[[:blank:]]`).